# CloudFront distribution id

Tags: java, amazon-s3

I want to invalidate files on Amazon after I've put them.
But I' confused with the DistributionID:

> private AmazonS3 s3;
>   private AmazonCloudFront cloudFront;
>
> ```
> ...
>
> AWSCredentials cred = new PropertiesCredentials(
>               AmazonWorker.class.getResourceAsStream("AwsCredentials.properties"));
>
> s3 = new AmazonS3Client(cred);
> cloudFront = new AmazonCloudFrontClient(cred);
>
> ...
>
> PutObjectResult por = s3.putObject(new PutObjectRequest(bucketName, path, is, metadata));
> List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>() {};
> list.add(bucketName + "/" + path);
>
> CreateInvalidationResult res = cloudFront.createInvalidation
> (
>   new CreateInvalidationRequest
>   (
>   "DistributionId",
>   new InvalidationBatch
>   (
>       list, 
>       UUID.randomUUID().toString()
>   )
>   )
> );
> ```

So, where could I get "DistributionId"?

Answer (score 4):

The DistributionID is shown in the Management Console after you create the Distribution:

[image]

Comment: Got DistributionID, but there is another error:  User: ... is not authorized to perform: cloudfront:CreateInvalidation

Comment: Ensure the User has the appropriate CloudFront permissions in IAM.